# Is it possible to have readonly access users in a private team?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have started with Stack Overflow for Teams where I work and currently there is a pilot phase (only about a dozen users). I have discussed with my manager about increasing the usage and I was asked if it is possible to have read-only access to the platform.

The question makes sense for our management team because, as already happens in the public Stack Overflow, only a small fraction of the total users are expected to contribute and management is less inclined to pay for licenses for all those users who will never contribute.

Is it possible to have read-only access users in a private team?

Comment: Can you not view the SO for Teams content on your intranet/hosted URL while not logged in? I'm assuming, of course, that by "private team" you mean private to your organization rather than public to the whole internet.

Comment: @TylerH AFAIK, teams does not offer self hosting

Comment: @TylerH - yes, it is the standard Stack Overflow for Teams offered by Stack Exchange. One may have a normal (or administrator) account in SO for Teams and it is counted as an active user.